# deserialize a json response that expects a dictionary but gets a list

Tags: c#, json, solr, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a response from solr in json:

This is the JSON:

```
"facet_counts":    {
 "facet_queries": {},
 "facet_fields": {"attraction":      [
   "Cape Winelands",
   2,
   "Col de Bonhomme",
   2,
   "Elephanta Caves",
   2,
   "Kruger National Park",
   2,
   "Manuel Antonio Park",
   2,
   "San Francisco Monastery",
   2,
   "Tafraoute",
```

In XML this would be:

```
    <lst name="facet_counts">
      <lst name="facet_queries"/>
           <lst name="facet_fields">
              <lst name="attraction">
              <int name="Cape Winelands">2</int>
              <int name="Col de Bonhomme">2</int>
              <int name="Elephanta Caves">2</int>
              <int name="Kruger National Park">2</int>
```

How do I deserialize the JSON as a Dictionary?

The issue is that the result is formatted as "Cape Winelands", 2 instead of "Cape Winelands" : 2

This is the way solr returns it, I don't have control over that and would prefer to use JSON instead of XML.

Anyone know how to do this? Or has run into this?

Comment: have you considered using SolrNet?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    "facet_counts": {
        "facet_queries": {},
        "facet_fields": {
            "attraction": [
                "Cape Winelands",
                2,
                "Col de Bonhomme",
                2,
                "Elephanta Caves",
                2,
                "Kruger National Park",
                2,
                "Manuel Antonio Park",
                2,
                "San Francisco Monastery",
                2
            ]
        }
    }
};

function arr_to_dict(a) {
    var o = {}, i, len, p;
    for (i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i +=1) {
        p = i%2?o[p]=a[i]:a[i];
    }
    return o;
}

arr_to_dict(data.facet_counts.facet_fields.attraction);
```

Comment: Yes, I can manually parse it. I'm wondering if there is a way to have the System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer in c# deserialize do it for me correctly. I'm curious if this json format is a mistake from solr or supposed to be this way.

Comment: You can write a class that inherits from the JavaScriptConverter, that implements the Serialize and Deserialize methods, and basically handle the Array to Dictionary conversion in the Deserialize method.  Then when you create your JavaScriptSerializer object, you can add the converter so that it knows how to convert the facets to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking about Solr, you can specify json.nl=map in the request parameters, which will return the facets in name value pairs as you need.